# Deploying grpc service to Azure

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, grpc

I am attempting to deploy a grpc C# service to Microsoft Azure with little success

I have tried to embed the service in a REST service Main, I have also tried to do it as a web job as well.  Both situations are erroring out attempting to connect to port 80.

**The real question is this - 
What is the proper way to deploy a grpc service to AZURE?**

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

**Update 12/7/2017 -** 
We are currently trying an App Service.  We were thinking that it had port 80 already open so we should be able to put it into a webjob and have it listen to that port there.  That did not seem to be able t o connect to the port, but locally it works.

I have not yet tried to launch a VM and open the port up there and see if maybe a windows service can work for it.  I think I will try that out next.

**Update 12/18/2017 -** 
Tried a Cloud service and that acts the same way, deploys fine though and theoretically is listening but nothing can talk to port 80 and be seen by the grpc server.

Comment: Do you try a Azure VM? https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html#download-the-example

Comment: Azure offers several ways to host web sites: Azure App Service, Virtual Machines, Service Fabric, and Cloud Services. How exactly are you hosting the service? 

If the service is on an Azure VM, please ensure that the Port 80 is open via NSG.
Refer the services comparison here for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm

 Also, checkout this discussion thread for different approaches:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1319

Comment: Based on what I can see on the web your best solution seems to be to go with an Azure VM or container service. Seems that others have issues with grpc and webapps.... In fact, a container service might be your ideal solution: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-container-instances/

Answer (score 0):

According to this discussion, Microsoft needs to make changes to both IIS and the Windows kernel:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9020

It is incredible that Microsoft has not been able to fix this for two years now.